# pytorchのインプレース操作のRunTimeErrorに関する解決策の質問です

Tags: python, pytorch

以下のコードでエラーが起きてしまいます．もしよろしければ，ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします．
質問し慣れていないので，至らないところもあるかもしれませんが，何卒よろしくお願いいたします．

**該当コード**（`torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)`によって表示された箇所）

```
class UnNormfunc(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UnNormfunc, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        tempx = x.clone()
        for i in range(3):
            tempx[:,i,:,:] = tempx[:,i,:,:] * std[i] + mean[i]
        return tempx
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "train.py", line 149, in <module>
    B_hat, B_hat_d1, B_hat_d2, B_hat_d3, B_hat_d4  = generator(torch.cat([ Norm(gamma_RF), Rmap, Norm(gamma_RF * Rmap) ], 1))
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "~/hoge/models.py", line 133, in forward
    D4 = self.unNorm(self.final4(x4_0))
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "~/hoge/util.py", line 30, in forward
    tempx[:,i,:,:] = tempx[:,i,:,:] * std[i] + mean[i]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 190, in <module>
    loss_G.backward()
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 102, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 90, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation
```

私にはインプレース操作を回避しているように見えるのですが，回避できていないようです．この理由をご教授お願いします
参考URL　http://www.yongfengli.tk/2018/04/13/inplace-operation-in-pytorch.html

Answer (score 2):

お騒がせいたしました。解決できました。原因はversionの違いみたいです。pytorchのversionを1.2.0にしたらうまく動きました。
質問を丁寧に修正いただいた方ありがとうございました。